NetworkKeyNotFound not found
I am trying to run collators node after securing and onboarding para_id by using this tutorial but, after running collator command:
./target/release/parachain-template-node --collator \
  --chain raw-parachain-chainspec.json \
  --base-path ./tmp/parachain/pubs-demo \
  --port 50333 \
  --rpc-port 8855 \
  -- \
  --execution wasm \
  --chain paseo \
  --port 50343 \
  --rpc-port 9988

I'm getting this error:
Error: NetworkKeyNotFound("./tmp/parachain/pubs-demo/chains/slaw_testnet/network/secret_ed25519")

Anyone have idea what mistake I'm doing here?
Github_repo

Have you attempted to clean the base-path?

@AurevoirXavier I have newly created base-path.

Which template repo and commit are you using?

@AurevoirXavier I have added gh repo above!

Unfortunately 404.

I'll reopen this if the link becomes accessible or if you can share additional details.

@AurevoirXavier sorry for delay I have just updated repo as public github repo.


Issue: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/issues/6730
PR: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/pull/3852

After introduced the #3852. The node won't generate the key automatically. That's why you can't do this in the latest version.
For local testing use --unsafe-force-node-key-generation, otherwise using generate-node-key.

It appears that you haven't provided the --node-key argument when starting your collator node. This argument is crucial for node identification and networking. Here's a step-by-step guide to generate and use a node key:
Step 1: Set Up the Environment
First, you'll need to clone the Polkadot SDK repository and compile the subkey tool:

Clone the repository:

git clone https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk.git
cd polkadot-sdk


Compile the subkey program:

cargo +nightly build --package subkey --release

Step 2: Generate the Node Key
Use the subkey tool to generate a new node key:
./target/release/subkey generate-node-key

This command will output two pieces of information:

A peer ID (public key)
A node key (private key)

Step 3: Save the Node Key
Save the node key (private key) to a file for future use:
./target/release/subkey generate-node-key > node-key

Step 4: Use the Node Key
When starting your parachain collator, include the --node-key-file option in your command, pointing to the file containing your node key:
./your-collator-binary --node-key-file /path/to/node-key [other options]

By following these steps, you'll generate a unique node key for your collator, which is essential for proper node identification and networking in the parachain network.
